# Pl Sql Procedure handle exception while scheduled using oracle scheduler

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, exception, jobs

I have written a procedure which will be scheduled using Oracle scheduler, and am trying to handle an exception using the following exception block:

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '
      || SQLCODE || ' -ERROR- ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

I also want to make sure if I use above support team or DBA come to know in case  of any exception and they can take appropriate action as well as all the transactions should  be rolled back.

Comment: This won't do anything other than mask the line the error occurred at. What is the purpose behind you wanting to handle the error? If it's to log the error to a file/table then you should have an error logging procedure (with pragma autonomous_transaction) that does the logging, which you would then call from your exception block before using RAISE to re-raise the error.

Comment: There is no specific purpose to handle error since it can be due to bad data whose nature is unspecified so we just want to notify and let support team know that there are  some issues , basically a log kind of facility . I don't want to create one more table and curious to know if there a way which support team can use to check this procedure outcome on weekly basis which will tell them whether procedure executed successfully or there were some issues with it .

Comment: `sqlcode` is just the number after `ORA`, so the concatenation turns `ORA-01234: Invalid whatever` into `-1234 -ERROR- ORA-012345: Invalid whatever`. I can't see what value that adds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only reason for the exception block is to notify the support team - don't do it, since it's completely superfluous.

Oracle logs the outcome of every job run in the views `XX_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUNS` / `XX_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS`, where XX is one of `DBA`/`ALL`/`USER` (User contains all runs for the currently logged-on user, All contains all runs the currently logged-on user is allowed to see, and DBA (which requires special privileges) contains all runs in the database.

So all your support team has to do is monitor `XX_SCHEDULER_JOB_RUN_DETAILS` and check for any entries with status `FAILURE`.

**Example**

Create a job that always fails, and run it once:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'JOB_RAISE_DEMO'
     ,job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK'
     ,job_action => 'begin raise_application_error(-20001, ''custom error''); end; '

     ,start_date      => to_timestamp_tz('2015-11-20 13:00:00 Europe/Berlin',
                                         'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss tzr')
     ,repeat_interval => null
     ,enabled => TRUE
     ,auto_drop => false);
end;

begin
  dbms_scheduler.run_job('JOB_RAISE_DEMO', use_current_session => false);
end;
```

Then, check the job status:

```
select log_date, job_name, status, error# 
from user_scheduler_job_run_details 
where job_name = 'JOB_RAISE_DEMO';
```

This returns:

```
LOG_DATE                        JOB_NAME        STATUS  ERROR#
20.11.15 12:35:53,516000 +01:00 JOB_RAISE_DEMO  FAILED  20001
```

Comment: Thanks , this looks valid justification , however can I rollback  like below :  EXCEPTION
       when others then
              ROLLBACK; Please let me know .

Comment: DBMS_SCHEDULER performs an automatic ROLLBACK when an exception is raised. Just try it, and you'll see that no data is changed when the procedure raises an exception (unless your procedure itself performs a COMMIT, of course).